# Having trouble deploying React-Express app to Heroku

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, mern

I'm trying to deploy a MERN app (built with create react app) to Heroku, but whenever I try to access the app URL, it returns with a 404 error.

I've checked the Heroku error log, which has returned the following errors:

```
app[web.1]: ls: cannot access '/app/build/static/js/*.js': No such file or directory
Error injecting runtime env: bundle not found '/app/build/static/js/*.js'. See: https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack/blob/master/README.md#user-content-custom-bundle-location
```

I've structured my project so that it runs on two different servers: client side on localhost:3000, which proxies requests to express at localhost:5000.

I've run `npm run build`, set up static middleware, and tried to configure my api calls/routes correctly, but it still isn't working. Any suggestions as to why, and how I can fix it? Details as follows:

**Project Structure**

```
+client
   |
   +-build
      +-static
        +-css
        +-js
        +-media
   +-node_modules
   +-public
   +-src
     |
     +-components
        +-App.js
        +-index.js
//server
+-models
+-node-modules
+-package-lock.json
+-package.json
+-server.js
```

**Proxy (in package.json):** 
 `"proxy": "http://localhost:5000"`

**Heroku build scripts (in client/package.json):**

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "heroku-postbuild": "cd client && npm install --only=dev && npm install && npm run build",
```

**Server config:**

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));


//Middleware
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build')));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.urlencoded())
app.use(cors())

app.get('*', (req,res) =>{
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/client/build/index.html'));
});
```

Here's how I;ve structured my APIs. Note: I've removed the 'localhost:5000' from the URL of my axios requests:

**API call from React component:**

```
    useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('/api/all-reviews')
    .then(review => {
        setReviews(review.data)
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    })
},[])
```

**Corresponding express route**

```
app.get('/api/all-reviews', (req,res) => {
    Review.find()
    .then((result) => {
        res.send(result)
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    })
})
```

Comment: Are your frontend and backend running on the same or different servers? (i.e. does your backend serve your frontend as static files?)

Comment: They're running on different servers: client side on port 3000, and then server side on 5000. I've set up my project so that all client side requests are proxied to the server on port 5000, though.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options,

#1 - make all urls relative, e.g. `fetch('/api/all-reviews')`, and have both the frontend and backend running on the same server. Serve the static build files from your backend (found in the `build` folder after running `npm run build`, assuming you are using create-react-app) using the `express.static` [middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html).
Note that you can do this in production while still relying on a proxy in development using `process.env.NODE_ENV`. An example implementation would be

```
// put this at the end of your server.js file

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/build')));
}
```

#2 - run the backend and frontend on different servers, and just adjust the path based on whether the code is running in development or production
Just as an example:

```
const prefix = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? "http://heroku_app_address" : "http://localhost:5000"
function getUrl(relativeUrl) {
   return prefix + "/" + relativeUrl;
}

fetch(getUrl('api/all-reviews'));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was wondering though, where exactly in my project should the `getUrl` function be? I have a file in my `src` folder called `helperFunctions` where I've put it for the time being, and am exporting it into the components I need. Once imported into the particular component, could I use it like this? `axios.get(getUrl(api/all-reviews))`. And last question, do I need to set up a .env file at all? Cheers

Comment: `helperFunctions` sounds like a good place for it. A .env file is needed if you are using the popular npm module dotenv - that loads your custom environment variables from a .env file into process.env . Otherwise, you don't need such a file. In heroku, you can set environment variables with `heroku config:set VAR_NAME=value`